# cross product and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{align*}\alpha _1=\left(a_{11},a_{12},a_{13}\right),\alpha _2=\left(a_{21},a_{22},a_{23}\right),\alpha _3=\left(a_{31},a_{32},a_{33}\right)\tag{1}\end{align*}$$

Then cross product(Can you explain me how to get 2 from 1)

$$\begin{align*}\alpha _2\times \alpha _3=\left(A_{11},A_{12},A_{13}\right)\tag{2}\end{align*}$$

A is the algebraic minor of a

Comment: We can simply check the components on each side of the equality are equal no?

Answer (score 1):

One can define the cross product of $n-1$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$. This is the case $n=3$. Consider two arbitrary vectors $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ in $\Bbb R^3$. Consider the function $$\phi(v)=\det\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2\\ v\end{pmatrix}$$

This is a linear function $\phi :\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$. It follows$^{1}$ there exists a unique  $z\in \Bbb R^3$ such that $$\langle z,v \rangle =\varphi(v)$$

This $z$ is called the cross product between $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ and denoted $\alpha_1\times \alpha_2$. From this definition, you can recover what $z$ should be. $$\langle \alpha_1\times \alpha_2,v\rangle=\det  \begin{pmatrix}
   {{\alpha _{11}}} & {{\alpha _{12}}} & {{\alpha _{13}}}  \\ 
   {{\alpha _{21}}} & {{\alpha _{22}}} & {{\alpha _{23}}}  \\ 
   {{v_1}} & {{v_2}} & {{v_3}}  \end{pmatrix}  = \left( {{\alpha _{12}}{\alpha _{23}} - {\alpha _{13}}{\alpha _{22}}} \right){v_1} + \left( {{\alpha _{13}}{\alpha _{21}} - {\alpha _{11}}{\alpha _{23}}} \right){v_2} + \left( {{\alpha _{11}}{\alpha _{22}} - {\alpha _{12}}{\alpha _{21}}} \right){v_3}$$

$1$. Follows by duality.

---

In general, one defines the cross product $\alpha_1\times \alpha_2\times\cdots\times \alpha_{n-1}$ as the unique $z\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $$\langle z,v\rangle=\phi(v)=\det\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2\\ \vdots\\ \alpha_{n-1}\\ v\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

When I calculate cross product, I always do this.
I think it is quite easy to memorize calculation of cross product this way

Let $\hat{i}, \hat{j}, \hat{k}$ be unit vectors in the direction of x-, y-, z-axis respectively.

Then the cross product between $\alpha = (a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3})$ and $\beta = (b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3})$ is given by the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k}\\a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3}\\b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3}\end{vmatrix}.$$

When you expand this determinant, the result is just the same as what you have mentioned above.